# sed to extract units of texts with multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a SQL dump and would like to extract only CREATE TABLE statements without comments. Here is how the content of the file looks like:

```
...
--
-- Name: static_data_agencyprogram; Type: TABLE; Schema: llcdb; Owner: llc_app
--

CREATE TABLE static_data_agencyprogram (
   id integer NOT NULL,
   source_branch_list text NOT NULL,
   fac_id public.citext NOT NULL,
   "limit" double precision NOT NULL,
   business_line_id integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE static_data_agencyprogram OWNER TO llc_app;
...
```

I tried the following to match 'CREATE TABLE', append next line to the pattern space, print the pattern space if the line starts with ");":

```
 sed -n '/^CREATE TABLE/{
 N
 /^);/n
 }' /var/tmp/db_tab.dump
```

the result does not meet my expectation. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straight forward with `awk` using an empty record separator:

```
awk -v RS= '/^CREATE TABLE /' file.sql
```

```
CREATE TABLE static_data_agencyprogram (
   id integer NOT NULL,
   source_branch_list text NOT NULL,
   fac_id public.citext NOT NULL,
   "limit" double precision NOT NULL,
   business_line_id integer NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. To print only `CREATE TABLE` statements.

```
awk '
!NF{
  found=""
}
/CREATE TABLE/{
  found=1
}
found
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** simply looking for string `CREATE TABLE` in line if its found then setting the found to `1`. Then checking condition if found is NOT NULL then print that line. Now coming to very first condition `!NF` which means on an empty line nullify found variable, to stop printing from that line onwards until again next `CREATE TABLE` is coming in line.